# ARIMAX vs VAR comparison

Tags: arima, vector-autoregression

With a time series Y of interest and another time series X that possible explains a part of Y, I came up with using ARIMAX and VAR models to model. 
What is the difference?

Thanks,

Comment: The model formulas should tell you the difference. Are you after anything more specific?

Comment: Hi Richard, forgive I'm sort of new to this field. Both arimax and var seems multivariate time series analysis with external variables into effect (one ext variable for arimax while several for var). What Im interested is the use case criteria when to use arimax or vma. My KPI for now is to model Y with the best of fitness either by using itself or using X or both. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From a theoretical perspective, VAR does not include moving-average (MA) terms and approximates any existing MA patterns by extra autoregressives lags, which is a less parsimonious solution than directly including MA terms as in an ARIMAX model. On the other hand, VAR can be estimated using OLS or GLS which are generally fast, while ARIMAX requires maximum likelihood estimation which is generally slow.

Whether VAR or ARIMAX provides a better representation of the underlying process in your application is an empirical question. You could try fitting both and doing some validation. E.g. construct a rolling window within your sample, fit a VAR and an ARIMAX model in it, and predict one step ahead. Roll the window all the way, collect the one-step-ahead forecasts from the two models and compare their accuracy. The model generating the higher accuracy is to be preferred.

Rob J. Hyndman has a brief note on ARIMAX and related models in his blog: ["The ARIMAX model muddle"](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/), perhaps it will be of help.

Comment: There's VARMA model, which adds MA terms to VAR.

Comment: Thanks. Since the question was framed as a comparison of two models, I just described these two, but the VARMA model is of course a relevant alternative.

Comment: >Richard, thank you for your input first and foremost. One follow up about validation is that, is there any useful R command(s) for rolling several windows or you usually script a loop to roll windows?

Comment: I just write a loop. Maybe it is not the most efficient way but it usually works for me. I know that "rugarch" package has built-in function for rolling various kinds of GARCH models and perhaps an ARFIMA model (potentially with exogenous regressors), while "rmgarch" package can roll a DCC-GARCH model with a VAR model for the conditional mean; perhaps you could use them somehow. But it could be simpler to write a loop yourself. I don't know a useful package for rolling ARIMAX/VAR models.